# Could jOOQ(Java)-SQL translator API be self hosted?

Tags: java, sql, jooq, translators, jooq-codegen-maven

I am using https://www.jooq.org/translate/ to translate SQL queries, and I want to translate SQL into jOOQ (Java) statements.

Can the program for to this API provide an installation package for self-hosting?

I want to deploy this API on my own server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a pending feature request to offer the translator as an out of the box web service for the jOOQ Enterprise Edition, but you can also easily roll your own using the [jOOQ parser as a programmatic API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/). Perhaps, [the parser CLI](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-cli/) can be taken as a source of inspiration on how to do this?

The [`SQLDialect.JAVA`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#JAVA) dialect used in your screenshot is available from the jOOQ Professional Edition.